# How to change unique index as non unique index in heidisql?

Tags: mysql

In below query I need to change `IMEI_CODE` and `REGISTRATION_ID` `unique index` as `non unique index` using `alter query`.How to achieve that

```
CREATE TABLE `ringee_user` (
    `RINGEE_USER_ID` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    `USER_NAME` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    `IMEI_CODE` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    `REGISTRATION_ID` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    `MOBILE_NUMBER` VARCHAR(14) NOT NULL,
    `CREATED_DTTM` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `MODIFIED_DTTM` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `IS_DELETE` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`RINGEE_USER_ID`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `REG_ID_UNIQUE` (`REGISTRATION_ID`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `MOBILE_NUMBER_UNIQUE` (`MOBILE_NUMBER`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `IMEI_CODE_UNIQUE` (`IMEI_CODE`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;

ALTER TABLE `ringee_user`
    CHANGE COLUMN `IS_DELETE` `IS_DELETE` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT '0' AFTER `MOBILE_NUMBER`;
```

Comment: I think you need to drop the index and re-create it.